# Chomsky hierarchy type determined by language

Tags: automata, proof-techniques, computation-models

I have some modified automata and the task is to give the type of Chomsky hierarchy to it.
All task is between type 3 and 0 noninclusive.
For regular languages there are lot of tools and I can check it without problems, Turing Machine equivalent is also easy task, and there will be no such examples.

Now the question: is it sufficient to show that automaton can accept specified language of given type?
From what I checked it would be sufficient to show equivalence to for example to NPDA, so I assume that if machine handles language that at least NPDA accepts it would be sufficient.

For example if machine can accept $a^nb^n$, it is type 2.
If machine can accept $a^nb^nc^nd^n$ it is type 1?
If not are there better examples of such languages or what steps should I follow?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Note that there's always the possibility that the given model is not equivalent to *any* Chomsky class. It may fall between two of them, or be incomparable to some (or all).

Comment: I am interested in full capability. If something is able to handle type 2 and not full type 1, but is more powerfull than type 2, it is perfectly enough to tag it type 2 and do not investigate any further. I know there are types in between - it is not important. Question is about such test - is my assumption valid? If it is not, I do not know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: For example CFL $L = \{\omega\omega^r, \omega \in \{a, b, c\}^+ \}$ so I would check if machine can accept it, if it does is it able to handle CFL? If not what should I check apart of this?

Comment: No, of course not; why would any finite test bank characterise CFL? That said, it so happens that there *is* a neat characterisation for CFL; see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19799/98).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a finite set of languages does not (usually) characterise infinite classes of languages. So any such specific tests are probably easy to fool.

For CFL in particular, there the [Chomsky-Schützenberger](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19799/98) characterisation. So if your model can deal with finitely many types of nested parentheses, it's *probably* at least as powerful as NPDA.

The generic proof technique for showing that one model is more powerful than another is *simulation*. You can find some examples via [simulation](/questions/tagged/simulation) and, of course, in the literature.

Proof of the opposite is usually done by *counter-example*, i.e. a language that can be expressed in one but not the other model.

Comment: Thank you. Answer is more than I expected. And for given test, well I assumed that some kind of test showing for example recursion would be good, but I had nothing to support this conjecture.